# how to provide dynamic input for Sql statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, dynamic-sql

I am trying to execute a dynamic sql query in python. It looks like below.

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal
import psycopg2

def initial_execution(param_name):
    time = get_timestamp(param_name)
    query = 'SELECT name, account_mgr, addr1, addr2, ap_email, bill_to_nbr, billto_only, city, controlling_nbr, controlling_only, country, cust_contact, email, load_create_date, load_update_date, nbr, owner, sales_rep, source_system, state, station, zip FROM public.customers WHERE billto_only = 'Y' OR controlling_only = 'Y' AND load_create_date >= \''+time+'\' OR load_update_date >= \''+time+'\''
    queryData = execute_db_query(query)
```

execute_db_query -> this function runs in the redshift using pscopg2
I am executing this script by dynamically pulling the "time" from a user input. I am getting an error

```
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module
'src/customers': 
invalid syntax (customers.py, line 78) 
Traceback
(most recent call last):   File "/var/task/src/customers.py" 
Line 78 query = 'SELECT name,billto_only, controlling_only , load_create_date, load_update_date, nbr, owner, sales_rep,
 source_system, state, station, zip FROM public.test WHERE billto_only
 = 'Y' OR controlling_only = 'Y' AND load_create_date >= \''+time+'\' OR load_update_date >= \''+time+'\''
```

The same query in sql is written like below and executes correctly

```
SELECT name,billto_only,  controlling_only,load_create_date, load_update_date, nbr, owner, sales_rep, source_system, state, station, zip FROM public.test
WHERE (billto_only = 'Y' OR controlling_only = 'Y') AND (load_create_date >= '2020-10-09 07:04:51' OR load_update_date >= '2020-10-09 07:04:51') limit 5;
```

Comment: What packages do you use? Show us the code you tried to execute the query with.

Comment: Dynamo querys are very different compared to SQL Querys, that is your problem.

Comment: Please use parameters instead of building a string, see [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be off the mark, but the 'Y' will be breaking your string?

```
query = 'SELECT name,billto_only, controlling_only , load_create_date, load_update_date, nbr, owner, sales_rep, source_system, state, station, zip FROM public.test WHERE billto_only = \'Y\' OR controlling_only = \'Y\' AND load_create_date >= \''+time+'\' OR load_update_date >= \''+time+'\''
```

Escaped apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

The error occured because `'` symbol,

```
"SELECT name, account_mgr, addr1, addr2, ap_email, bill_to_nbr, billto_only, city, controlling_nbr, controlling_only, country, cust_contact, email, load_create_date, load_update_date, nbr, owner, sales_rep, source_system, state, station, zip FROM public.customers WHERE billto_only = 'Y' OR controlling_only = 'Y' AND load_create_date >= '{date}' OR load_update_date >= '{date}'".format(date=time)
```

Comment: Please do not show this sort of query building, for the reasons shown [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Answer (score 0):

A correct way of doing this:

```
query = """SELECT 
name, account_mgr, addr1, addr2, ap_email, bill_to_nbr, billto_only, city, controlling_nbr, 
controlling_only, country, cust_contact, email, load_create_date, load_update_date, nbr, 
owner, sales_rep, source_system, state, station, zip 
FROM 
    public.customers 
WHERE 
    billto_only = 'Y' OR controlling_only = 'Y' 
AND 
    load_create_date >= %(time_val)s OR load_update_date >= %(time_val)s
"""

queryData = execute_db_query(query, {"time_val": time)
```

The above ensures that the data passed in is correctly quoted and prevents SQL injection issues.
I would also avoid using variable names like `time`. That is a potential conflict with `time` module as well a `time` type in Postgres.